Given $k\in\mathbb{N},\exists\ n\geq 2$ such that $\{t^n\pmod k:t\in\mathbb{N}\}=[k].$
Proposition:

Define $[m]:= \{0,1,\ldots,m-1\}.$ Given $k\in\mathbb{N},$ $\exists\ n\geq 2$ such that
$\{t^n\pmod k: t\in[k]\} = [k].$

This is the same as proposing:

Given $k\in\mathbb{N},$ $\exists\ n\geq 2$ such that
$\{t^n\pmod k: t\in\mathbb{N}\} = [k],$

because any integer $t$ can be written as $t=ik + j$ for some $i\in\mathbb{Z},\ 0\leq j\leq k-1.$ Then  $t^n\equiv(ik+j)^n\equiv j^n\pmod k,$ by the Binomial theorem.

If $k$ is prime then by Fermat's Little Theorem, we can let $n=k,$ for then $t^n\equiv t^k\equiv t\pmod k.$
But what if $k$ is not prime? I tried considering $n=k!\pm1\ $ or $\ n=\left(\displaystyle\prod_{\text{p is a prime and } p\leq k} p\right) \pm1,\ $ but I don't see a way forward. Maybe Chinese remainder theorem can help... but how?

I came up with this problem myself when thinking about some facts I knew about numbers in modular arithmetic such as: If $k=5$ then I know that $n=2$ does not work. But then I tested $n=3$ and it turns out it does work. Then I came up with the general proposition above.

Have you checked $k=4$?  Seems to answer it quite early.

Also, it's not true in general for $n\gt 1$. A simple example is $k=4$, as Brian's comment indicates, and the residue $t=2$. In general, it doesn't work for any integer that's not square-free. Note that, offhand, I'm not sure about square-free integers in general.

That's fine: that answers the question.

For square-free integers, I believe you'd have a positive answer by Fermat's little theorem.

As pointed out in the comments, this is false for $k=4,$ and it doesn't work for any integer that is not square-free. Further investigation could be done on square-free integers.

For $k = \prod p_i$ try $n=1+\prod (p_i-1)$

for $n\neq 1$ this is not always possible. for example $ k = 9 $, for all $2\le n $, $3^n \equiv 9^n$ (mod k). therefore $|${$t^n$ (mod $k$): $ t \in \Bbb N$}$|$$\le 8$ and as a consequance {$t^n$ (mod $k$): $ t \in \Bbb N$}$\neq [k]$. I believe this would also be generally wrong with $k$ not prime. if you are trying to maximize |{$t^n$ (mod $k$): $ t \in \Bbb N$}|, I suggest you use $n = \varphi(k) +1 $, where $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function
